# crontab failed with exit status 12

Tags: bash, cron

from syslog

```
May  8 01:00:01 mvtspro-main /USR/SBIN/CRON[22645]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ky4k0b/cdrs_backup_daily.sh)
May  8 01:00:01 mvtspro-main /USR/SBIN/CRON[22638]: (CRON) error (grandchild #22645 failed with exit status 12)
```

from /etc/crontab

```
mvtspro-main:/cdrs/backup# cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
25 6    * * *   root    ntpdate pool.ntp.org
0 1 * * *       root    /usr/local/ky4k0b/cdrs_backup_daily.sh
0 2 1 * *       root    /usr/local/ky4k0b/cdrs_backup_monthly.sh
0 3 1 * *       root    /usr/local/lib/mvtspro/backupdb.php
```

my script

```
mvtspro-main:/cdrs/backup# cat /usr/local/ky4k0b/cdrs_backup_daily.sh
#!/bin/sh
mask=`date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d\*`
arch_name=`date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d`
find /cdrs -type f -name "$mask"|zip -m /cdrs/backup/$arch_name.zip -@
```

where did I make a mistake? Thanks!
PS: If I run this script manually it works fine.

Comment: You need to indicate the script executing the script. Change to `0 1 * * *       root  /bin/sh  /usr/local/ky4k0b/cdrs_backup_daily.sh`

Comment: nope, didnt work. Still status 12

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem with cron. In my case it was excessive output from tar not getting directed anywhere so it would block the script after the buffer ran full. Redirecting output of the called script to /dev/null worked for me (or maybe it was setting MAILTO="").

Comment: very weird but the problem was resolved after I restarted cron

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

this worked